# Work on data from different worksheets in a single worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an Excel file that consists of worksheets named 1, 2, 3, and so on. These worksheets involve data that I would like to analyze in the same ranges. I want to analyze these data in a single worksheet (Let's called it Master Worksheet).

So, to give an example, for the B2 cell of the Master worksheet, I would like to take average of the range B2:B11 of worksheet 1. For C2 cell, I would like to take the minimum of C2:C11 of worksheet 1, and so on.

Similarly, for B3 cell of the Master worksheet, I would like to take average of the range B2:B11 of worksheet 2. For C3 cell, I would like to take the minimum of C2:C11 of worksheet 2, and so on.

For this, I could not find any shortcuts in Excel, so I thought writing an VBA code would work. However I am not very familiar with it, so I am a bit stuck.

```
Sub MasterWorksheet()
Dim i as integer
Dim TotalNumberofWorksheets As Integer
TotalNumberofWorksheets = 99
For i to TotalNumberofWorksheets:
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Worksheet").Cell(2, i+1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B2:B11").Average()
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Worksheet").Cell(2, i+1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C2:C11").Min()
...
End Sub
```

I tried this, however it did not work. Any idea on how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a For loop is

```
For i = 1 To TotalNumberofWorksheets 'you can make it start at i=2 too if need be
'or go backwards from TotalNumber and then use TotalNumberofWorksheets Step = -1
    'your code here
Next i
```

So no need for `:` after the end-step and a needed `i = startValue`

I doubt you have 99 worksheets in your workbook, hence why I would change your code to

```
Sub MasterWorksheet()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TotalNumberofWorksheets As Integer
    TotalNumberofWorksheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To TotalNumberofWorksheets
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name <> "Master Worksheet" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Worksheet").cell(2, i + 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B2:B11").Average()
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Worksheet").cell(2, i + 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C2:C11").Min()
            'etc
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This way you also have a security to not include the master sheet.